# linq orderby first item in collection

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sorting

How do you do OrderBy on a collection within an entity?

For example, this sorts Customers by Name (string)

```
entities.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name) ...
```

If Customer had an Orders property that was a collection of Order entities and for some reason you wanted to sort Customers on that (lets say by order date), can you do that?

```
entities.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Orders.?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how to sort customers without orders, so

```
var query = entities.Customers
                    .Where(c => c.Order.Any())
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Orders.FirstOrDefault().Date)
```